# Can one purchase a SIM card at Yangon International Airport (RNG) between 1 AM and 8 AM?

Tags: airports, cellphones, myanmar, yangon, rgn

Can one purchase a SIM card at Yangon International Airport (RNG) between 1 AM and 8 AM?

---

What I have found so far:

I couldn't find information on https://yangonairport.aero. On https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294190-i9408-k10670366-Buy_SIM_card_at_Yangon_airport-Myanmar.html someone claims that SIM card shops (MPT, Telenor, and Ooredoo) are open until 8 or 9 PM but doesn't mention the opening time.

On https://ooredoo.com.mm/portal/en/businesslocatus I can see that the opening time is from 9 AM to 9 PM for the 2 Ooredoo airport stores (1 located at the international terminal and  1 located at the domestic terminal).

[image]

On https://www.mpt.com.mm/en/home/support/store-location/ I could see the phone numbers but no opening time (which I'll call if I can't find the information somewhere else and doesn't resort to purchasing a prepaid SIM card online before heading to Yangon International Airport):

- Yangon International Airport, Mingalardone Tsp, Yangon. 09-421062793
- Yangon International Airport (Domestic) , Mingalardone Tsp, Yangon. 09-450244836

I couldn't find the information about Telenor, and whether there is any other SIM card seller in the airport aside from MPT, Telenor, and Ooredoo.

Comment: What about an alternative - eg buying in town? Or the fact there's free wifi at the airport - is that enough for your purpose?

Comment: @MarkMayo I'll be flying to Bagan at 8:45 am, and would prefer to have a sim card before the flight so that I don't waste time on it in Bagan (my stay there is short). I would prefer not to go too far from Yangon airport so as to reduce cab fare (if I spend 10 USD on cab then I would instead buy some SIM card online before going to Myanmar) and increase sleep time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one can purchase a SIM card at Yangon International Airport (RNG) between 1 AM and 8 AM: the Ooredoo shop and the Telenor shop in the international terminal (terminal 3) are opened 24 hours a day, as of November 2019.

[image]

Price was about 1000 kyats for one GB, with a SIM card for 90 days from what I recall. Can be recharged online at the same rate.